# Sending data without redirect?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to send data to the client without having it redirect and show the data in the browser. The server is written in node.js using express.js.
It is for a login function.
I need to have it work like this since the idea of the system is to use the front-end purely as a GUI for interacting with the API.

```
res.send("Login failed").redirect(homepage);
```

I've seen framework-engine which I suppose I could use, but I would like to avoid as much additional "software" as possible. Essentially my question is: How do I send data back to the client so that it can be used in an already shown HTML page.

Comment: Instead of submitting the page on a login form, use ajax to send a request to your back end, and update the status on-page if it fails (or redirect to homepage if success). Good place to start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX

Comment: @Gavin Post this an answer and you got yourself a solution mark.

Comment: Nah it's okay. Nudge in the right direction hardly a comprehensive solution. The MDN docs are great.